# OpenGL ES 1.1 Color over Font Texture

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, colors, fonts, textures

I currently have a texture serving a font, that is on the topmost (last) render in OpenGL for the iPhone. The texture is white glyph with a transparent surround. My aim is to have another color overlayed on the texture, effectively changing the font color.

Using the code below I can make a solid color on the texture, provided the alpha is set to 255. My aim is to have a progressive color fade out, so my aim is to display the color (0,0,255,127). This should be a partially transparent blue. However I have tried many times with glTexEnv() settings and cannot seem to make a non-solid color overlay.

```
glBlendFunct(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
glColorub(0,0,255,255);
...
glDrawElements(...);
```

I have tried the suggestions at the OpenGL wiki page http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Combiners, under the title of *"Example : Blend tex0 and tex1 based on alpha of tex0"*. Also I have tried the idea found here [OpenGL ES 1.1: How to change texture color without losing luminance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361023/opengl-es-1-1-how-to-change-texture-color-without-losing-luminance).

If there any setup I can get to make the color (0,0,255,127) present, without losing the outline of the font/character?

PS. Another idea was to pass a pre-multiplied alpha color (such as (0,0,255*(127/256),127)) for the preceding example, but this seems not too elegant.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I intend for the character texture to retain full opacity, just to color overlay to change. Thus the example should change from full blue to full white.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change glBlendFunc parameters (BTW there is a typo in glBlendFunct).

Take a look at this:
http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glBlendFunc.3G.html

For me setting it to:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

works.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Beppe. Unfortunately this has a similar outcome as described above. If I were to try (0,0,255,40), the whole texture becomes nearly transparent. If I could, the result needed is the background texture (at full 255 alpha) with the light blue on top. Thus to the user, the color is light blue, but the character is fully opaque.

Comment: Mmm... I still think you should achieve your goal through glBlendFunc. Have you tried to play around with other possible parameters?